# iMac with mdnsresponder keeps waking up

Tags: macos-sierra, mdns, wake-on-lan

I am trying to figure out why my iMac 2011 wakes up so frequently (every ~2 min)
If anyone can help, I would be really greatful.

Here is my pmset log:

```
2017-05-03 22:14:31 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=5662]
2017-05-03 22:15:28 +0300 Assertions            PID 214(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008556 [System: DeclUser BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]
2017-05-03 22:15:30 +0300 Assertions            PID 214(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:02  id:0x0xd00008556 [System: DeclUser BGTask kDisp]
2017-05-03 22:15:43 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDN] due to GIGE/Network: Using AC 45 secs
2017-05-03 22:15:43 +0300 WakeDetails           DriverReason:Enet.Service - DriverDetails:
2017-05-03 22:15:43 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [PRT1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(330 ms)] [IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1106 ms)] [IOUSBMassStorageDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1175 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderInterfaceNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(1107 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 2)(1172 ms)] [PRT0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(14532 ms)] [AppleAHCIDiskQueueManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(319 ms)]
2017-05-03 22:16:32 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=6429]
2017-05-03 22:17:28 +0300 Assertions            PID 214(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008563 [System: DeclUser BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]
2017-05-03 22:17:30 +0300 Assertions            PID 214(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:02  id:0x0xd00008563 [System: DeclUser kDisp]
2017-05-03 22:17:43 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDN] due to GIGE/Network: Using AC 45 secs
2017-05-03 22:17:43 +0300 WakeDetails           DriverReason:Enet.Service - DriverDetails:
2017-05-03 22:17:43 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [PRT1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(331 ms)] [IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1102 ms)] [IOUSBMassStorageDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1169 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderInterfaceNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(1103 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(1179 ms)] [PRT0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(14622 ms)] [AppleAHCIDiskQueueManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(318 ms)] [IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(14316 ms)]
2017-05-03 22:18:33 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=6427]
2017-05-03 22:18:49 +0300 Assertions            PID 214(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000856d [System: DeclUser BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]
2017-05-03 22:18:51 +0300 Assertions            PID 214(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:02  id:0x0xd0000856d [System: DeclUser BGTask IPushSrvc kDisp]
2017-05-03 22:19:03 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] due to EHC2/HID Activity: Using AC 31 secs
2017-05-03 22:19:03 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [PRT1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(332 ms)] [AppleHDADriver driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(473 ms)] [AppleHDADriver driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(402 ms)] [IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1064 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderInterfaceNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(1069 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(1136 ms)] [IOUSBMassStorageDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1143 ms)] [PRT0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(14250 ms)] [AppleAHCIDiskQueueManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(318 ms)]
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 2017-04-30 08:42:37 +0300 :418   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:2
2017-05-03 22:19:34 +0300 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Software Sleep pid=126': Using AC
2017-05-03 22:19:53 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=6429]
2017-05-03 22:20:35 +0300 Assertions            PID 214(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000085be [System: DeclUser BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]
2017-05-03 22:20:37 +0300 Assertions            PID 214(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:02  id:0x0xd000085be [System: DeclUser kDisp]
2017-05-03 22:20:50 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] due to GIGE/UserActivity Assertion: Using AC
2017-05-03 22:20:50 +0300 WakeDetails           DriverReason:Enet.Service - DriverDetails:
2017-05-03 22:20:50 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [PRT1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(331 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderInterfaceNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(1106 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 2)(1169 ms)] [IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1112 ms)] [IOUSBMassStorageDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1178 ms)] [AppleHDADriver driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(474 ms)] [AppleHDADriver driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(400 ms)] [PRT0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(14526 ms)] [AppleAHCIDiskQueueManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(319 ms)] [IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 4)(14300 ms)]
Total Sleep/Wakes since boot at 2017-04-30 08:42:37 +0300 :419
```

and the packet capture of the ethernet device:

[image]